# Ctrl-y behavior in gnuplot - not yanking in OS X

Tags: macos, gnuplot, ctrl

Typically, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> yanks previously killed text. This works very well in the terminal to cut and paste text. However, once I start gnuplot, using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> suspends the program. The odd thing is that this only happens in my OS X machine. On my Ubuntu 12.04, the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> inside the gnuplot has the expected behavior of yanking text.

Any ideas ideas on why this is happening? And how can I make <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to have the expected behavior in a interactive gnuplot session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an educated guess -- OS-X does not ship with gnu readline, so gnuplot (by default) builds against the native OS-X readline implementation.

```
print GPVAL_COMPILE_OPTIONS  #... +READLINE_IS_REALLY_EDITLINE ...
```

To fix this, you'd probably need to download/install gnu readline and then compile gnuplot with `--with-readline=gnu` or something to that effect.

Comment: (+1) You're probably right. I can't check because I didn't compile gnuplot against `libedit` but `GNU readline`. An alternative would be to use [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/).